# Added/dropped columns in local table not updated in the distributed one in Clickhouse

Tags: clickhouse

I'm working with a two-node ClickHouse cluster where each node houses multiple ReplicatedMergeTree tables. Replication among these nodes is functioning as expected. For every ReplicatedMergeTree table, there's an associated Distributed table, which we use for all insert and read operations.

However, I've run into an issue when making schema changes, such as adding or dropping columns from the local tables. Even though these changes are correctly replicated across the cluster, they aren't reflected in the corresponding Distributed tables. From my understanding, a Distributed table acts as a virtual proxy, so it should inherently recognize changes made to the local tables.

To validate this, I've used the DESCRIBE command on the Distributed table, and it still displays the old schema, not the updated one. As a workaround, I find myself having to recreate the Distributed table with every schema migration, which is not ideal.

Is there a better way to handle this or something I'm missing? Any guidance on why the Distributed table isn't automatically reflecting the changes from its underlying ReplicatedMergeTree tables would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The process is not automatic.  You need to make the same schema changes to your distributed table.  Often it's just easier to drop and recreate the distributed table using CREATE dist_table AS source_table ON CLUSTER.

Distributed tables can differ from their source tables in various ways (different databases, different permissions, etc.), and automatically keeping distributed tables "in sync" would have various side effects.

One way to get what you want is to use the experimental "Replicated" database engine, which actually does keep an "internal" Distributed table in sync, but the table itself just looks like a MergeTree.